# Event Propagation without directive in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I would like to know if there is a way to propagate events from within a route to outside the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

The scenario is like that we have a route say Home, & HomeComponent should notify about something to the root component. If it was a direct child of app.component we could have used EventEmitter type output property in HomeComponent & event binding on `<home (eventName)="actionName()"></home>` directive. But it is not the case as HomeComponent is used from within route.

Please help me out by suggesting the proper way for event propagation from route to root component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a shared service that is injected in the sender and receiver component to communicate (like a message bus). For more details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Or you can use `element.dispatchEvent()` to fire a bubbling event. See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent for more details.